# Upload Google Contacts C# token expire

Tags: c#, google-api, google-contacts-api

I wrote a code which is delete all contacts from a google account contact list and upload new contact list. I am using Outh2 to authenticate. Everything is working fine, but the access token expire after 1 hour. The error code is 401. Can someone help me how to solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["token"];
        string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]; ;


        string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/" }; 
        try
        {

            UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                         , scopes
                                                                                         , "myaccount@gmail.com"
                                                                                         , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                         , new FileDataStore("test")).Result;

            OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
            parameters.AccessToken = credential.Token.AccessToken;
            parameters.RefreshToken = credential.Token.RefreshToken;
            parameters.AccessType = "offline";
            UploadContacts(parameters);
        }
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use following credential.Token.IsExpired methode in my code. It works fine in the project below.

```
    UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
{ 
   ClientId = Google.ClientId, ClientSecret = Google.ClientSecret },
   scopes,
   settings.GoogleAccount,
   CancellationToken.None).Result;

   // check token is expired
   if (credential.Token.IsExpired(credential.Flow.Clock))
   {
      if (credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result)
      {
         //The access token is now refreshed. 
      }
      else
      {
         //The access token has expired but we can't refresh it
      }
   }
   else
   {
      //The access token is OK, continue.
   }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Andreas

https://www.andreasulbricht.de/cctsync/